# Meaning of a "having come to be required"

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrases

What does the following mean?

> "having come to be required".

It is meaning of statutory?

Comment: @FumbleFingers is correct but perhaps not quite clear. The phrase implies that while at one time it might not have been necessary to do a particular thing, it is now 'required' to do that thing. If a law ( a 'statute') had been passed, for example, then something that was once voluntary becomes 'required'.

Answer (score 1):

It is a descriptive phrase. It means that something wasn't required in the past, but now it is required.

Using it in a sentence requires the tense of the verb "have" to be adjusted. In the quote the particple "having" is used, but you might need to use "have" or "has":

> An id card has come to be required when voting in parts the USA.

The dictionary is defining a meaning of "statutory", which describes something that is now mandatory. The word is often used figuratively, to mean something you do because you are now culturally expected to do it, not because you enjoy it.